# Can I implement FTPS and HTTPS in STM32F303RC board?

Tags: ssl, ssh, https, stm32, ftps

Hello I am using STM32F303RC card and W5500 Ethernet shield My question is simple I want to know if it is possible for me to implement SSL / TLS all the datasheets I see exclude the F3 family, so please help me determine if that's possible or I'm wasting my time looking for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the microcontroller nor the Ethernet chip appear to support hardware acceleration of encryption.  You can still implement encryption in software but it will be very slow.

You have tagged this question both SSL and SSH, which makes it sound like you aren't really sure what you want.  I suspect that finding and integrating a software crypto library to work in this set up will be a big challenge for you.  You might find it a lot  easier to change the hardware.  Otherwise, good luck!